# 20.04 Livepatch question

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

In 20.04 I enabled `Livepatch`. I've watched it for two weeks, and haven't seen it do anything, so I decided to disable it.

However, I still see a process `canonical-livepatch` running, and I still see a snap application `canonical-livepatch`.

Is the snap application starting the `canonical-livepatch` process?

Can I safely remove both snap and process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable livepatch and remove your machine-token:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch disable
```

and for remove it:

```
sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch
```

---

whenever you want enable it, login https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/ and get your livepatch token, then:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable 'LIVEPATCH-TOKEN'
```